# Check the following are subspaces of v

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]

Actually I know how to check subspace but in this I don't get any idea how to proceed please help

Comment: Hmmm... you have no idea for all the $5$ parts? what are the properties of a subspace that you have difficulty checking?

Comment: Start by checking if the sum of two things in $W$ is still in $W$.

Comment: Some of these are clearly not closed under scalar multiplication, e.g. (v).

Comment: Actually I don't able to think about function which satisfy these properties.....

Comment: @siong thye goh like in part (I) of mine for checking to be subspace f(0)=1,g(0)=1 f+g(0)=1 but actually closed addition doesn't satisfy so it's mean I part doesn't subspace is I am correct?

Comment: Yes, it is not a subspace. Include all your attempts in the question itself rather than type it in the comment.